# Pandas: Apply indexed list of values to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

I have a dataframe:

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'target': [0   ,0   ,0   ,0   , 300, 400, 500, 600, 0],
                   'class' : [0  ,0   ,0   ,0   ,   1,   1,   1,   1,   0],
                   'feature':[12 ,13  ,13  ,200 , 900, 800, 600, 600,  12]})
```

And I've a process that's generated an indexed set of updates, expressed either as a pair of lists:

```
update_index  = [0 ,  1,  2,   3,   8]
update_values = [20, 25, 25, 150,  25]
```

Or, I can express these as a list of tuples:

```
update_tuples = [(0,20), (1,25), (2,25), (3,150), (8,25)]
```

Or, ideally, I'd like to be able to express them as a pair of numpy arrays - since this is more likely to be the form I'll generate them in.

```
update_index_array  = np.array([0 ,  1,  2,   3,   8])
update_values_array = np.array([20, 25, 25, 150,  25])
```

Expression options aside, I have found a method for updating my dataframe with the values in my value-set, at the locations specified in my index-set, and this works, but it's kind of slow (and ugly!).

```
[my_df.set_value(i,'target',v) for i,v in update_tuples]
```

This is a problem because in my real-life example, I have many thousands (millions?) of updates to perform.

What I'd like to find is some kind of numpy-accelerated single-shot update (i.e. no list comprehension) that blats the updates into the appropriate target positions, without over-writing the existing values in the non-indexed positions.

Any thoughts please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, this is certainly *not* how you would do this in `pandas`. Instead, use indexed-assignment:

```
>>> my_df.loc[update_index_array, 'target'] = update_values_array
>>> my_df
   class  feature  target
0      0       12      20
1      0       13      25
2      0       13      25
3      0      200     150
4      1      900     300
5      1      800     400
6      1      600     500
7      1      600     600
8      0       12      25
>>>
```

As an aside, you should *never* use a comprehension like this:

```
[my_df.set_value(i,'target',v) for i,v in update_tuples]
```

List comprehensions are not just fancy ways of writing for-loops, they are for *creating new lists*. This is mixing a functional programming construct, the list comprehension, with state-change i.e. `my_df.set_value`. That is simply incoherent style. But worse, it is also wasteful because you are creating a useless list of references to the same dataframe. Instead, just use a for-loop. An analogous situation would be something like:

```
>>> my_list = []
>>> [my_list.append(i) for i in range(5)]
[None, None, None, None, None]
>>> my_list
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Don't do that. Just use the for-loop if you are going to be using side-effects.

Comment: Just the ticket, thankyou - and yes, I kind of felt instinctively that the list comprehension wasn't the right way to go. Your explanation helps put some context behind that intuition, so thankyou for that as well.